# Extract certain words from strings of text in Excel cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2013, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a column of cells filled with a lot of text. I only need one word from each cell. If you look closely you will see that the latter part of each cell says either High, Medium, or Low.

[image]

I want to create a column next to this one that extracts this word (High, Medium, or Low) from the text string. My initial thought was to extract based on position, but the words are in varying positions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will return the correct value:

```
=INDEX({"High","Medium","Low"},AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($1:$3)/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*" & {"High";"Medium";"Low"} & "*",A1))),1))
```

It iterates the possible words and returns the one that does not return an error as a number in order to the INDEX.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know a function to extract part of a string inside two unique characters. e.g:  `-Medium-` will be `Medium`.

This is the formula:

`=MID(A3,SEARCH("-",A3)+1,SEARCH("-",A3,SEARCH("-",A3)+1)-SEARCH("-",A3)-1)`

In order for this to work, you will need to convert your text as shown in the photo below to add the unique character (in this case a dash `-`). You can do it using the find and replace `CTRL+H` as follows:

1. Select the column that has the text to extract.
2. Press `CTRL+H` key combination
3. Find what: `Low`
4. Replace with: `-Low-`
5. Click on `Replace All` button.
6. Repeat from step 3 to 5 for `Medium` and `High`.

See the output below:

[image: here]

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple approach that uses wildcards.

[image]

The formula in B1:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A1,"*Low*"),"Low",IF(COUNTIF(A1,"*Medium*"),"Medium",IF(COUNTIF(A1,"*High*"),"High","")))
```

It's just some nested IFs to check whether each term is contained in the cell.  I added an extra IF test in case there could be a record that does not contain any of the terms (returns a blank).